# Use database function 'NOW()' in datatable editor

Tags: php, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I would like to set a timestamp value indicating when a particular operation was undertaken. That will involve me setting a time value before creating a record, something similar to this.

```
->on( 'preCreate', function ( $editor, $values ) {
        $editor
         ->field( 'datetime_created' )->setValue( '2014-03-19 11:44:40' );
        } )
```

I use php code to set the datetime variable. I would like to use the database function ***NOW()*** instead.

I presume it would be something almost similar to this:

```
->on( 'preCreate', function ( $editor, $values ) {
        $editor
          ->field( 'datetime_created' )->setValue( 'NOW()' );
        } )
```

But off course its now working.

What options does the datatable editor give me to effectively use database functions?

Comment: Try this,Declare one varrible and store `NOW()` and `setValue` with that variable

Comment: Does your database not support `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? Much easier that way.

Comment: That will require me to create a whole new query (SELECT NOW()) outside the editor.I was looking to do it within the editor.

Comment: Just do `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` it's unlikely you'd need split-second precision in the created date. @NiettheDarkAbsol's solution is much better though.

Comment: Seems I will look into @NiettheDarkAbsol's. Thanks.